# What's wrong with this natural deduction proof?

Tags: predicate-logic, fake-proofs, natural-deduction

According to natural deduction $\forall$ $x$ $\exists$ y $P(x,y)$ $\models$  $\exists$ $x$ $\forall$ y $P(x,y)$ is incorrect. However I am able to prove the following using the rules of natural deduction. Consider this proof:

1. $\forall$ $x$ $\exists$ y $P(x,y)$ ------------- data
2. $\exists$ y $P(a,y)$  ----------------- $\forall$ elimination
3. $P(a,e)$ --------------------- $\exists$ elimination
4. $\forall$ x $P(x,e)$ ----------------- $\forall$ introduction
5. $\exists$ $y$ $\forall$ x $P(x,y)$ ------------ $\exists$ introduction

Clearly this proof must have something wrong with it but I cant seem to figure out where?

To clarify the inference rules I have used:

1. $\forall$ elimination says that for a formula $\forall x$F we may derive the conclusion F(x/a) where a is any element from the domain
2. $\forall$ introduction says that for any formula F(x/a) where a is an arbitrary element  from the you can derive the $\forall x$F
3. $\exists$ elimination says that for a formula $\exists x$F we may derive the conclusion F(x/e) where e is a specific element of the domain
4. $\exists$ introduction says that for any formula F(x/e) where e is a specific element from the you can derive the $\exists x$F

Comment: Step $4$ is wrong.   $P(a,3)$ does not imply  $P(x,e)\;\forall x$

Comment: If you treat $\forall$ and $\exists$ identically, then you'll always encounter problems. How does your proof work, semantically?

Comment: You'd have to show us your exact axioms to indicate the problem, but, as lulu points out, step $4$ is awfully fishy. $2+3=5$ does not let us concludes $\forall x: x+3=5$.

Comment: When you eliminate $\exists$,you start a new subproof with the constant $e$ at the start. You're then trying to conclude $\forall xP(x,e)$ within this subproof, but you can't because you'd need $P(a,e)$ at the same level as the declaration of the variable $a$, and it isn't.

Comment: What do you mean a new subproof? Does a new subproof begin every time any quantifier gets eliminated? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RaeesRajwani I can't. I may even have misspoken, because the details depend on your inference rules. Can you please post them and how to use them unambiguously?

Comment: @RaeesRajwani OK, this helps. But in order to really get to the problem, the definition of *proof* is necessary. Was this given to you?

Comment: @GitGud This is just something im trying on my own because I want to see the logical flaw in my argument. I understand that there is a counterargument that makes it invalid but I cant seem to find the reason the argument holds.

Answer (score 3):

You have misunderstood the use of $\exists$-Elimination in step 3: the rule is **not** [Existential instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation).

With $\exists\text{E}$ :

> $$\dfrac{∃x \phi(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ \phi[t/x] \vdash \psi}{\psi}$$

we do not *infer* $\phi[t/x]$ from $∃x \phi(x)$ but - having $∃x \phi(x)$ in our derivation - we **assume** $\phi[t/x]$. In addition, $t$ must be a *term* and not an element of the domain.

This means that with $\phi[t/x]$ we start a sub-proof with it as open assumption.

Thus, we cannot apply $\forall\text{I}$ to it with $x$ as variable to be "generalized" [and again, we "generalize" a variable, and not an element of the domain], due to the proviso of the rule $\forall\text{I}$:

> $$\dfrac{\phi(x) }{\forall x \ \phi(x)}$$
>
> where the variable $x$ may not occur free in any hypothesis on which $\phi(x)$ depends.

---

In your purported derivation, if we replace $a$ with a free *variable*, we have :

2) $∃ y P(x,y)$ ----------------- $∀$ elimination

3) $P(x,e)$ --------------------- assumed for $∃$ elimination

4) $∀ x P(x,e)$ ----------------- $∀$ introduction : **wrong**, because $x$ is free in the assumption 3).

Answer (score 0):

From 1. to 2., you "dropped" the $\forall x$, and try to restore it between 3. and 4. This can't be.

Comment: This is not the problem : 1) $\forall x P(x) \vdash P(y)$ --- by $\forall$-elimination, followed by : 2) $P(y) \vdash \forall z P(z)$ --- by $\forall$-introduction, is a correct derivation.